# Parse and save lines from text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to scan a text file that has a format like this:

```
reviewers: 0
open: Sunday 08:00 16:00,Monday 06:00 20:00,Tuesday 06:00 20:00,Wednesday 06:00 20:00,Thursday 06:00 20:00,Friday 06:00 20:00,Saturday 06:00 01:00
name: The Lyre of Orpheus
city: San Francisco
cost: $$
category: Greek,Breakfast & Brunch,Seafood,Salad,Soup
rank: 0
```

and saving each line as a string or double, but i keep getting null with the sys.out.println inside of my forloop, anything I can change? My thought is that I'm resetting my variables inside my try too early or something.

```
 public class Yulp {
//instance vars
ArrayList<Restaurant> resList = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Yulp yelp = new Yulp();
    yelp.scan();
    for(int i = 0; i < yelp.resList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(yelp.resList.get(i).getCity());
    }

}

public void scan() {
    try {
        Restaurant tempRes = new Restaurant();
        String name, city, category, cost;
        double rank, reviewers;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("randomizedList.txt"));
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            //name = null; city = null; category = null; cost = null; rank = 0.0; reviewers = 0;
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String rest = omitPrefix(line, "reviewers:");
            if (rest != null) {
                reviewers = Double.parseDouble(rest);
                tempRes.setReviewers(reviewers);
            }
            rest = omitPrefix(line, "rank:");
            if (rest != null) {
                rank = Double.parseDouble(rest);
            }
            rest = omitPrefix(line, "name:");
            if (rest != null) {
                name = rest;
            }
            rest = omitPrefix(line, "city:");
            if (rest != null) {
                city = rest;
            }
            rest = omitPrefix(line, "category:");
            if (rest != null) {
                category = rest;
            }
            rest = omitPrefix(line, "cost:");
            if (rest != null) {
                cost = rest;
            }
            resList.add(tempRes);
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}

private String omitPrefix(String line, String prefix) {
    if (line.startsWith(prefix))
        return line.substring(prefix.length());
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use `BufferedReader`? It has a method called `readLine()` that would work like a charm for your problem

Comment: By the way, use `temp.startsWith("reviewers:")` instead of `temp.equals("reviewers:")`

Comment: The Scanner class has methods that can be used to test what type of data will be read next.  There names start with hasNext...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Snippet {
  public void scan() throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("randomizedList.txt"));
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
      String line = scan.nextLine();
      String rest = omitPrefix(line, "reviewers:");
      if (rest != null) {
        System.out.println(rest);
      }
      rest = omitPrefix(line, "name:");
      if (rest != null) {
        System.out.println(rest);
      }
      rest = omitPrefix(line, "city:");
      if (rest != null) {
        System.out.println(rest);
      }
      rest = omitPrefix(line, "category:");
      if (rest != null) {
        System.out.println(rest);
      }    
    }
    scan.close();
  }

  private String omitPrefix(String line, String prefix) {
    if (line.startsWith(prefix)) 
      return line.substring(prefix.length());
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Snippet().scan();
  }
}
```

Main points:

- Instead of `line = new Scanner(scan.nextLine()); temp = line.nextLine();` you can just do `scan.nextLine`.
- For getting the remainder of a line (for instance the part that follows the "name:" part) I introduced a helper method called `omitPrefix(line, prefix)` which returns `line` sans `prefix` if `line` starts with `prefix`, or `null` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it.

```
public class FileParser {
    public void scan() {
      try {
        File list = new File("randomizedList.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(list);
        String temp;
        Scanner line;
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            line = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
            temp = line.nextLine();
            if (temp.startsWith("reviewers:")) {
                System.out.println(temp.split(":",2)[1]);
            }

            if (temp.startsWith("name:",1)) {
                System.out.println(temp.split(":",2)[1]);
            }

            if (temp.startsWith("open:")) {
                System.out.println(temp.split(":",2)[1]);
            }
            if (temp.startsWith("city:")) {
                System.out.println(temp.split(":",2)[1]);
            }

            if (temp.startsWith("category:")) {
                System.out.println(temp.split(":",2)[1]);
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        System.out.println("File's MISSIN!");
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("NoSuchElementException dangus.");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FileParser().scan();
}
```

}

Check the line with `startsWith` to find the introductory key word.

Then use `split` the string around the `:` which returns an array of two strings.

The second string in the returned array is reached by `[1]` and this produces the above output

There are further improvements that can be made to this code though.

The if statements should be refactored and extracted as a separate method.

The strings constants should extracted and each line should only be checked once.

Once a match is made you should move on to the next line.